# Why projective linear spaces are simple ???

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, simple-groups

In classical groups, people project all those linear groups and make it as simple. Why do they so, Why can't linear groups can be restricted to simple instead of projecting on the scalar space.

What does that projection geometrically imply in that PSL, PSpn,(symplectic) , unitary, orthogona; etc

Comment: Your question is completely unclear. Are you asking why $PSL_{n}$ (and other similarly defined groups) are simple?

Comment: Why projection comes into play ?? We can alter linear groups and make it as simple instead applying projection ..

Comment: I still don't understand. Let's take $SL_{n}$ as an example. We can show that $SL_{n}$ has a nontrivial proper normal subgroup and that $PSL_{n}$ is simple. What is the alternative simple group associated to $SL_{n}$ that you want to look at?

Comment: "If the question doesn't look clear to me, let's close it!" ... do the closers here, instead of waiting for the expert for whom it was clear.

Answer (score 3):

Projection removes central subgroups. "S" removes abelian quotients. Iwasawa's theorem says that: If a group (a) has no abelian quotients, (b) acts primitively, and (c) is generated by the conjugates of a solvable subgroup, then it is simple. Part (b) typically requires the projection.

There are lots of cases where a matrix group does not need to worry about "P" or "S": for example $\operatorname{GL}(n,2)$ is a finite simple group for all $n \geq 3$ and $\operatorname{SL}(n,3)$ is a finite simple group for all odd $n \geq 3$. However, in order to ensure simplicity, one takes "P" and "S", since the abelian quotients and central subgroups exist for many fields and many types of groups.